# Camera animation here SDK

Tags: here-api

Any tips how to do nice camera animation with the here SDK for flutter I can take examples from IOS or Android SDK.
The issue I’m facing is that in the example it shows animation with pre known camera zoom/distance to earth source and target.

In my example it’s difficult to find the right distance to earth given a bounding box and also find the center of a bounding box finally find the right bounding box to be able to comfortably see a set of GeoCoordinates.

Any tips much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There's nice bow-type [animation example](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/camera_app/lib/CameraExample.dart) for Flutter. It's using custom Tweens.

If you want to zoom to a set of coordinates, use the `MapCamera`'s `calculateEnclosingCameraUpdate()` method. It allows to zoom to a bounding box you can get from a route with `route.getBoundingBox()`. This way you can ignore the distance or center as the camera will automatically find the right value.